# getLoginUrl: session and cookie is lost after redirect

Tags: php, facebook, session, cookies

I need to store some data in a session or cookie and access it after the permission dialog. My problem is, that the top.location.href redirection that is called after the user gave permission, seems to delete my cookie and session. So I am not able to do the following:

store data in session or cookie ---> get user permissions ---> redirect after permission dialog ---> access session or cookie set before the permission request

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your webserver is not sending out p3p headers correctly and the cookie is not being stored correctly.

For information on how to set your p3p headers see:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx